# SLD to CSS. Geoserver CSS module problem

Tags: geoserver, sld, geoserver-css-module

I styled Geoserver maps with SLD. And now I have to convert this style to CSS. CSS is easier to support. Well, I have this fragment of SLD:

```
<Geometry>
    <ogc:Function name="offset">
        <ogc:PropertyName>way</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>-13</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>13</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
</Geometry>
```

I don't know how to use 'offset' function in CSS. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the CSS solution for geoserver:

[image]

```
             /* ---------------- BUILDING ------------- */

                    /* @title Building 60K - 5K */
            [building='yes'][@scale>5000][@scale<60000],
            [building='house'][@scale>5000][@scale<60000]
             {
              /* In EPSG900913 so offset equates to meters */
              geometry: [offset(way, 8, -6)], [way];
              fill: black, #696969;
             } 

                    /* @title Building 5K - 3K */
            [building='yes'][@scale>3000][@scale<5000],
            [building='house'][@scale>3000][@scale<5000]
             {
              /* In EPSG900913 so offset equates to meters */
              geometry: [offset(way, 5, -4)], [way];
              fill: black, #696969;
             } 

                     /* @title Building 3K - 0K */
            [building='yes'][@scale<3000],
            [building='house'][@scale<3000]
             {
              /* In EPSG900913 so offset equates to meters */
              geometry: [offset(way, 3, -2)], [way];
              fill: black, #696969;
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the label properties? Have you checked the docs?

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/css/properties.html#text-symbology-labeling

Answer (score -1):

*The offset function can be used to create drop shadow effects below polygons. Notice that the offset values reflect the fact that the data used in the example is in a geographic coordinate system.* (from [Geometry transformations in SLD](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/geometry-transformations.html))

A CSS equivalent for your SLD code could be this:

```
box-shadow: -13px 13px 0px #888888;
```

You may test this code [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_box-shadow)

Comment: This is not your regular CSS, rather the question refers to the CSS Module in Geoserver which is a CSS Syntax Editor that then converts the entered CSS style into the appropriate SLD for use by Geoserver.